# Flask debug mode stuck at "Restarting with stat"

Tags: python, flask

I don't know what have happened, but after months of developing a PythonFlask project, I suddenly cannot run it in debug mode. Python gets stuck at displaying:

- Restarting with stat

When running via Visual Studio, it just remains like that, the IDLE Python Shell waits there for a bit and then returns to >>> prompt as the program has escaped without any errors.

The problem isn't in my code, the same happens when simply trying to run an empty Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
Flask(__name__).run(debug=True)
```

If debug is on False, it all runs perfectly, but that makes development significantly more uncomfortable.

I've tried a couple of Python versions, even re-installed, didn't work.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The way I run my flask application in debug is through the socketio runner. `socketio.run(app,host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)`. You will need to download eventlet or gevent to run the app. You can learn more here: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Using `Flask.run` is not advised.  The developers of Flask recommend using the framework to run your app `$ FLASK_ENV=development flask run`

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Might be worth writing your comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was having the same problem with debug=True. Selecting the legacy debug checkbox in the options seemed to enable reloading after changes without needing to restart. But now it doesn't automatically launch the website when i click on start, you have to manually type in localhost:xxxx in the browser.

Following are the steps that worked for me in Visual Studio 2019:

1. select options from the tools drop down
2. select python
3. select debugging
4. check the "Use legacy debugger" option(it was unchecked by default)

[image: screentshot of the option]

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to replicate your problem, however, the Flask [developers recommend](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/server/#command-line) using the cli instead of the object's API:

```
FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_ENV=development flask run
```